# How to read ChangeLog of plugin in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm writing a plugin. In that plugin I have 1 example. I want to display package change information in this example by changelog file  of plugin and showing it to the user.

My problem comes from read the changlog File. I tried the same thing when I wanted to load a json file in the application's assets. However, it still doesn't work with writ a plugin

In MethodChanel File:

```
 @override
  Future<String?> getPackageVersion() async{
    String text = await rootBundle.loadString("CHANGELOG.md"); //await f.readAsString();
    return text;
  }
```

in pubspec.yamle File:

```
  plugin:
    platforms:
      android:
        package: com.upos.vn.printer_v3
        pluginClass: PrinterV3Plugin
      ios:
        pluginClass: PrinterV3Plugin

  # To add assets to your plugin package, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - CHANGELOG.md
```

Answer (score 1):

Assets can only reside within the `assets/` directory, otherwise you'll have to use `File` to read the file, but depending on where you run this you might not have access to it.

So move your `CHANGELOG.md` to `assets/` (create it if it doesn't exist) and then in your `pubspec.yaml`:

```yaml
  assets:
    - assets/CHANGELOG.md
```

If you still want to have the file in the root of the project too, which you probably do, you could symlink it from the assets directory. Just make sure that it is the real file that is in the assets directory and that the symlink is in the root, otherwise you'll get problems publishing on some platforms.

Comment: Have a small problem here. Currently my ChangeLog is for the plugin. If I move it to assets. This will not be valid when pushing the library to pubdev. Pubdev requires a ChangeLog file in the root directory.

Comment: If I try, I think I will create 2 changelog files, one stored in root and one stored in assets. However, hopefully there is a better solution.

Comment: @TrầnVănHiếu did pub not accept a symlinked changelog?